# How To Create Supabase Table In Flutter?

Tags: flutter, create-table, supabase

I want to make a chat application, where every user contains a table.. for that when new users register in the app. I have to create the table in supabase for himself/herself manually from flutter code only. not from supabase UI or external Postgres client.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In most applications it's usually not a good idea to create a new table for each user - but if you must do it this way you can use https://pub.dev/packages/postgres to connect to the supabase postgresql instance directly using the postgres query string (found in database > settings). You can then write queries to set up tables in SQL from within flutter.

Make sure you don't expose the postgres connection string to the user, and that you sanitize any strings that are used to build the sql queries